# When do I use a Grignard reagent such as PhMgBr, instead of an organolithium such as PhLi to react with butanone

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

Essentially what I am asking is, how do I know whether I should use a Grignard in the place of an organolithium compound or vice versa when reacting it with aldehydes and ketones, or does it not matter as much for these carbonyl compounds?

Comment: I think it's down to what level of selectivity you need. If other groups are present on the ketone or aldehyde, which may be sensitive to an excessively reactive organometallic species, then you may want to tone it down. On the other hand, the more reactive one may be more appropriate in some cases. E.g. if you have an alpha-beta unsaturated ketone and you want the C=O carbon to be attacked rather than the C=C one, then you may be better off with PhLi. I seem to remember cuprates are appropriate for the C=C addition in this case. Then there is the problem of suppressing proton abstraction...

Comment: In case of 2-butanone it may be a question of what pre-prepared reagent you have available. For ease of preparation and scale-up, the Grignard is the way to go.